# how creat 3 dot square on bottom center of android screen by xml eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I use a picture to make a button by three square dot on on center bottom of screen android
but that look very bad on some screen when its solution or screen rate change.

I need help to make this by draw shape xml so it can fix on corect position, and size can look good in all screen

please help

thanks

Comment: Well, what you need is reading "Supporting multiple screens" http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html